# Get values from the key-value pairs in a comma separated string

Tags: c#

I have string value like below:

```
var result = "{DimensionTransactionMonth=August, DimensionTransactionYear=2012}"
```

I need to transform like below:

```
var finalResult = "August,2012";
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Read about regular expressions in .NET.

Comment: Or JSON serialization/deserialization

Comment: Is that a Json string? You can deserialize that to a .NET object

Comment: You can replace = with : and it will be

Comment: it still is missing quotes around the string value "August"

Comment: The string is not valid JSON. Parsing this manually should be fairly easy..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thus you are dealing with kev-value pairs, I would convert your input to `Dictionary<string,string>`:

```
var result = "{DimensionTransactionMonth=August, DimensionTransactionYear=2012}";
var settings = result.Trim('{', '}')
                     .Split(',')
                     .Select(s => s.Trim().Split('='))
                     .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

Now you can easily get final result:

```
var finalResult = String.Join(",", settings.Values); // "August,2012"
```

Or some specific value by its key:

```
var month = settings["DimensionTransactionMonth"]; // "August"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner so I can look clever, it doesn't depend on the `Count` of Key Value Pairs:

```
var result = "{DimensionTransactionMonth=August, DimensionTransactionYear=2012}";

var stringValues = string.Join(",", result.Trim('{', '}').Split(',').Select(x => x.Split('=')[1]));

Console.Write(stringValues);
```

Output:

```
August,2012
```

Having said that, I would go with Sergey Berezovskiy's solution for the `IDictionary` Lookup.

**Explanation:**

```
result.Trim('{', '}').Split(',').Select(x => x.Split('=')[1])
```

Broken Down:

```
1. .Trim('{', '}')
```

Removes the outer curly braces.

Result:  "DimensionTransactionMonth=August, DimensionTransactionYear=2012"

```
2. .Split(',')
```

Turns the result of step one into an Array split on the ','

Result: ["DimensionTransactionMonth=August", "DimensionTransactionYear=2012"]

```
3. .Select(x => x.Split('=')[1])
```

Projects each item from step two into a `IEnumerable<string>` as it does this it `Splits` `"DimensionTransactionMonth=August"` into `["DimensionTransactionMonth","August"]` and we take the Last value in that array `"August"`

No we can join this `IEnumnerable<string>` back together using `string.Join(',' ...)` like so:

```
string.Join(",", result.Trim('{', '}').Split(',').Select(x => x.Split('=')[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 steps (if you wish to do it manually like this).

**Remove the brackets**

```
var s = result.SubString(1, result.Length - 2);
```

**Split the key-value pairs**

```
var pairs = s.Split(new[]{','});
```

**Extract the values by splitting on the `=` sign**

```
var resultset = pairs.Select(x => x.Split(new[]{'='})[1]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = string.Join(",", result.Split(',').Select(o => o.Split(new[] { '=', '{', '}' })[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex (if there are only those two pairs):

```
string text = "{DimensionTransactionMonth=August, DimensionTransactionYear=2012}";
var token = text.Trim('{', '}').Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim());
string month = token.First().Split('=').Last().Trim();
string year = token.Last().Split('=').Last().Trim();
string finalResult = string.Format("{0},{1}", month, year);;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.Replace(); and string.Split();

```
var result = "{DimensionTransactionMonth=August, DimensionTransactionYear=2012}"

var splitValues = result.Replace("{","").Replace("}","").Split(",");

var month = splitValues[0].Split("=")[1];

var year = splitValues[1].Split("=")[1];

var finalResult = string.Format("{0},{1}", month, year);
```